# Formatting a time isn't working

Tags: php, strtotime, strftime

I'm trying to get a format for time working. I'm working with an app I inherited.

The time is stored in the table as 13:45:00

However, it is being displayed as 1pm . I want it to display as 1:45 PM

The data from the table is stored in a temp table with

```
$sql_temp="CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cache (id int(11) NOT NULL,event_link text,
...
            start_time varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            start_time_a varchar(255) NOT NULL,
```

start_time is from the original code that showed as 1pm
start_time_a is my attempt to show the hours minutes and meridian

The table with the start date is then read with

```
$start_time=date('ga',strtotime($event->start_time));
$start_time_a = $event->start_time;
```

Then it is inserted into the temporary table

```
$ins_qu="INSERT INTO cache (id, . . . ,start_time,start_time_a) VALUES(
                '".$start_time."',
                '".$start_time_a."'
```

I've put a couple of variations of trying to get the format right with

```
<div class="event-venuetitle event-venue-time">
    <?php echo $ve_n['start_time'];?>
    <?php echo ' || ' ?>
    <?php echo $ve_n['start_time_a'];?>
    <?php echo ' || ' ?>
    <?php echo strftime(' %r  ', $ve_n['start_time_a']);?>
    <?php echo ' ** ' ?>
    <?php echo strftime(' %r  ', formatted_time);?>
</div>
```

That gives me results like

```
9pm || 21:45:00 || 6:00:21 pm CST **
```

The 9pm is from the original code. 
21:45:00 is the raw time to string, I believe
 6:00:21 pm CST is when I tried to format with a strftime with a %r.

What do I need to do to get this to show a hh:mm AM/PM?

Comment: Try to replace `'ga'` with `'g:ia'` like so: `$start_time=date('g:ia',strtotime($event->start_time));` .. and see if that works across the board.

Comment: That did it !. I tweaked it a little to `'g:i a'` which gives me `9:45 pm` etc.  I was able to  use the original code and got rid of the start_time_a code I had put in .

Answer (score 3):

First convert your string to a UNIX timestamp by strtotime and then back into the format you require using the date function.

For example:

```
$Time = '05/12/2016 ' .  $ve_n['start_time'];
$newDateTime = date('h:i A', strtotime($Time));
```

In your example it be like:

```
<?php echo date('h:i A', strtotime('05/12/2016 ' .  $ve_n['start_time']));?>
```

and output be:

```
09:45 PM
```

Or using g instead of h, that not show leading zeros.And You can use without passing day, like here:

```
<?php echo date('g:i A', strtotime($ve_n['start_time']));?>
```

and output be:

```
9:45 PM
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `g` instead of `h`, as he didn't show he wanted leading zeros. And also, you don't need to give a day, as `strtotime` will assume 'today' if not provided (test it out, you'll see).